# Dropping rows in a pandas dataframe based on conditionals after slicing

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop the rows inside a pandas data frame whose 14th and 15th characters equal '00' (it's a string). I tried doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

for df in pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Workstation/.spyder-py3/AAPL.USUSD_Candlestick_1_M_BID_14.11.2018-28.11.2020 (1).csv',chunksize=60):
        
        a=-1
        for i in df["Local time"].str.slice(14, 16):
            a=a+1
            if i != '00':
                df.drop(df.iloc[a])
```

But it's not working. The error is:

```
"['14.11.2018 00:01:00.000 GMT-0500' 192.227 192.227 192.227 192.227] not found in axis"
```

How can this problem be fixed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = df[ df["Local time"].str[14:15] == "00" ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You put '!=' inside the code it should be '=='. But very helpful!